# Missing stack symbols with perf_event's perf report, despite -fno-omit-frame-pointer compilation

Tags: perf-event

I'm struggling getting perf_events to give me stack traces with symbols, despite reading many tutorials on the subject and doing (I think) all the necessary things. It's possible that my local install of perf (details on that below) is somehow botched? Anyway, here's what I did:

main.cpp is a simple C++ program that calls a few functions defined in the same file, allocates some memory and frees it, and prints a few things out.

compilation command:

```
gcc -std=c++11 -lstdc++ main.cpp -Og -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-inline -o arr_test
```

profile command:

```
perf record -a -g -- ./arr_test && perf report --stdio
```

I do get the following warnings about kernel symbols, but I don't think this should matter given that I only care about symbols in my application for now:

```
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.052 MB perf.data (~2285 samples) ]
[kernel.kallsyms] with build id e22966849c48748782a1be4fe0ce94db6838b806 not found, continuing without symbols
[kernel.kallsyms] with build id e22966849c48748782a1be4fe0ce94db6838b806 not found, continuing without symbols
Warning:
Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) were restricted.

Check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict before running 'perf record'.

As no suitable kallsyms nor vmlinux was found, kernel samples
can't be resolved.

Samples in kernel modules can't be resolved as well.
```

Here's a snippet of the output:

```
# Overhead   Command      Shared Object
# ........  ........  .................
#
    83.27%  arr_test  arr_test         
            |          
            |--34.12%-- 0x400908
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--10.48%-- 0x400903
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--10.08%-- 0x4008b8
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--9.22%-- 0x4008e5
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--9.05%-- 0x4008da
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--8.49%-- 0x4008f0
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--6.87%-- 0x4008d5
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--6.23%-- 0x4008c2
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
            |          
            |--4.76%-- 0x4008fd
            |          0x7fe72b381ec5
             --0.70%-- [...]

     8.02%  arr_test  [kernel.kallsyms]
            |          
            |--4.87%-- 0xffffffff81140b64
            |          0xffffffff81146646
            |          0xffffffff81182751
            |          0xffffffff811829eb
            |          0xffffffff8173317d
            |          0x7fe72bab86a7
            |          0x7fe72baa7e00
```

file info (shows "not stripped"):

```
$ file arr_test 
arr_test: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, not stripped
```

Details on my perf install (do any of these warnings prevent me from seeing symbols in stacks?)

```
Auto-detecting system features:
...                     backtrace: [ on  ]
...                         dwarf: [ OFF ]
...                fortify-source: [ on  ]
...                         glibc: [ on  ]
...                          gtk2: [ on  ]
...                  gtk2-infobar: [ on  ]
...                      libaudit: [ OFF ]
...                        libbfd: [ OFF ]
...                        libelf: [ OFF ]
...             libelf-getphdrnum: [ OFF ]
...                   libelf-mmap: [ OFF ]
...                       libnuma: [ on  ]
...                       libperl: [ on  ]
...                     libpython: [ on  ]
...             libpython-version: [ on  ]
...                      libslang: [ on  ]
...                     libunwind: [ OFF ]
...                       on-exit: [ on  ]
...                stackprotector: [ on  ]
...            stackprotector-all: [ on  ]
...                       timerfd: [ on  ]

config/Makefile:264: No libelf found, disables 'probe' tool, please install elfutils-libelf-devel/libelf-dev
config/Makefile:329: No libunwind found, disabling post unwind support. Please install libunwind-dev[el] >= 1.1
config/Makefile:354: No libaudit.h found, disables 'trace' tool, please install audit-libs-devel or libaudit-dev
```

How can I find my symbols in perf?

Answer (score 8):

I'm compiling using more debugging options:

```
-Og -ggdb3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

Then, when I record I'm not using -a option (that should monitor all the system processes), I'm using

```
perf record -e cycles -g --call-graph fp -- ./your_app your_args
```

Finally, to show the result I'm using

```
perf report -g graph
```

and the output looks like expected (note, I'm using debian 9 and the perf report output is ncurses based)

```
-   92.18%     0.00%  stsm     stsm                  [.] main                                                                                                ◆
   - main                                                                                                                                                    ▒
      - 91.77% STSM::run                                                                                                                                     ▒
         + 56.86% STSM::generateCandidates                                                                                                                   ▒
         - 25.22% STSM::detectBlocksOfAllSolidSequences                                                                                                      ▒
            + 23.42% STSM::detectSolidSequenceBlocksFromSolidSequence                                                                                        ▒
              0.81% Segment::unify                                                                                                                           ▒
         + 5.25% STSM::updateKernelsOfAllCandidates                                                                                                          ▒
           1.80% RangedSequence::range                                                                                                                       ▒
         + 1.45% STSM::updateMatchingPositions                                                                                                               ▒
           0.99% Segment::intersects                                                                                                                         ▒
+   92.18%     0.00%  stsm     libc-2.24.so          [.] __libc_start_main                                                                                   ▒
+   92.18%     0.00%  stsm     [unknown]             [k] 0x4d96258d4c544155                                                                                  ▒
+   91.77%     0.00%  stsm     stsm                  [.] STSM::run                                                                                           ▒
+   56.86%     6.74%  stsm     stsm                  [.] STSM::generateCandidates                                                                            ▒
+   49.99%    49.99%  stsm     stsm                  [.] Segment::intersects                                                                                 ▒
+   25.22%     0.00%  stsm     stsm                  [.] STSM::detectBlocksOfAllSolidSequences
```

Comment: In case someone is like me and hasn't realized that `-0g` will keep less information than `-O0`, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970596/gcc-4-8-does-og-imply-g/27076307#27076307

Comment: Nice comment @lol, follow your link I just learn that if you specify more than one -g* options (like in my original answer) than "the last such option is the one that is effective" (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) so I updated the answer to use just -ggdb3

Comment: Yes, unfortunately (or fortunately) gcc wouldn't warn you about that since it allows you to specify different arguments for different parts of the input parameters. Like the `whole-archive` flag for specific ar files.

Comment: This is still not working for me. Compiling with `-O0 -ggdb3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++20` (also tried `-Og`) and doing the rest as posted here; there are no function names whatsoever. Only "[unknown]".

Answer (score 4):

This is an old topic but am sure it still happens to hundreds of people and because this StackExchange question still shows up high on Google results, am sharing answer found on StackOverflow that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137543/linux-perf-top-kernel-symbol-not-found

Basically:

### Before starting perf record

`echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict`

### Also it might be necessary to setup these

For RHEL/CentOS/Fedora/etc

`yum install -y elfutils-libelf-devel libunwind-devel audit-libs-devel slang-devel`

Or for Debian/Ubuntu/etc

`apt-get install libelf-dev libunwind-dev libaudit-dev libslang-dev`

Comment: If Linux says "/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict: Permission denied" then try `sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict"`